# Client certificate for postman and Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, curl, https, postman

I need postman to connect to my server which requires client certificate. After some research, it seems that postman does not handle certificates itself but relies on Chrome certificates instead. My next step was to try to install the certificates in Chrome, my cert structure is like this:

Self-signed root CA => intermediate CA 1 => intermediate CA 2 => client cert

I have a file certchain.pem that contains client cert followed by intermediate CA 2 cert then intermediate CA 1 cert, I also have client.key file. I tried to install the chain in Chrome but it seems that Chrome requires pkcs12 so I split off certchain.pem into client.crt and middle.pem, then I convert everything to pkcs12 by:

`openssl pkcs12 -in client.crt -inkey client.key -certfile middle.pem -export -out client.p12`

I could install client.p12 into Chrome but it doesn't seem to retain the intermediate certs, when I choose View, it only shows info about client cert.

I've tested that client.p12 works by installing it into Firefox, there I can see info about the intermediate certs. I've tested that my certs work by doing a curl with them. Any other idea?